# Difference between two dates in Python formatted correctly

Tags: python, date, time

I'm working on a timing system, using Python. I am trying to work out the difference between the start time and the finish time.

```
startTime = 20181114171544
finishTime = 20181114182428
```

How can I display the difference between this dates in a nicely formatted h/m/s format?

Comment: What did you try? Take a look at datetime from the standard library and datetime.strptime function if you haven't already.

Comment: You have saved the date and time in an integer like this?

Comment: from datetime import datetime 
startTime = 20181114171544 
finishTime = 20181114182428 

I fixed this. Repeat this for both times...
y1 = int(str(startTime)[: 4]) 
m1 = int(str(startTime)[4: 6]) 
d1 = int(str(startTime)[6: 8]) 
h1 = int(str(startTime)[8: 10])
mi1 = int(str(startTime)[10: 12])
s1 = int(str(startTime)[12: 14]) 
date1 = datetime(a1, m1, d1, h1, mi1, s1) 
delta = date2 - date1 
raceTime=time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(delta.seconds))
print(raceTime)